# Gulp-notify compile error

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I am using [`gulpfile.js`](https://gist.github.com/Sigmus/9253068) but it is throwing compile time error for gulp-notify

Following is structure of package.json

```
{
    "name": "flux-pricing",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "Pricing component with flux",
    "main": "gulpfile.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "flux": "^2.0.0",
        "react": "^0.12.0",
        "underscore": "^1.7.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "envify": "~1.2.1",
        "browserify": "~4.2.0",
        "gulp": "~3.9.0",
        "gulp-notify": "~1.4.0",
        "gulp-util": "~2.2.19",
        "reactify": "~0.13.1",
        "vinyl-source-stream": "~0.1.1",
        "watchify": "~0.10.2"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "watchify -o js/bundle.js -v -d .",
        "build": "browserify . | uglifyjs -cm > js/bundle.min.js"
    },
    "author": "Ken Wheeler",
    "browserify": {
        "transform": [
            "reactify",
            "envify"
        ]
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the error? Please post it, so we can help you.

Comment: @gustavohenke I have added screenshot of error please check

Comment: I tried to use gulp-notify once. I couldn't use it because some plugins were throwing ASCII colored chars (for terminal), and this didn't play well with Windows `toastr.exe`. Maybe that's your issue?